# Searching by ID in MongoDB not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm setting up some basic searches in MongoDB, and while I'm able to find records by "ObjectId," I can't search by "_id". I'm conducting searches both directly in the Mongo console and writing search code in Atom, which I'm then running in a nodemon server.

```
 db.collection.find( { ObjectId( _id: "abcdefg" ) } ) // Returns a result
```

```
 db.collection.find( { _id: "abcdefg" } )             // Returns null
```

**The problem:** If I enter search (1) into the console, it returns a result, yet when I enter the same search into Atom and run through nodemon, nodemon throws an error because "ObjectId" is undefined. (2) Always returns null, regardless of where I enter the search.

Are there any workarounds for this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
db.collection.find({"_id" : ObjectId("abcdefg")})
```

Side note. It is a better practice to have your keys in double quotes in json. Make that in to a habit.

Comment: "It is a better practice to have your keys in double quotes in json" - in JSON double quotes around object keys are *required*, but when defining objects in JS - they are completely optional and unnecessary (unless your key has spaces/other special characters).

Comment: I am thinking by JS you mean Json. In [JSON](http://json.org/), objects are `{ string: value }` pairs so if you do not use the double quotes, it is handled internally. Therefore the "totally unnecessary" part of your statement is ironically unnecessary like your comment ... On the other hand, I really do not care. Do what you want.

Comment: Sorry if you took my comment badly, that wasn't the intention. I suggest you read about JSON a little more, especially its origin and actual definition. While originally derived from object notation used in JavaScript, it is not the very same thing. I remember being a little confused about it myself. To sum the difference up - as long as you're not serializing JavaScript objects (`JSON.stringify`), that's not JSON. And as long as you're staying away from actual JSON - the quotes around keys are totally optional (again, unless you have special characters in your key).

Comment: I appreciate your quick response! Whether you put a key in quotes or not in Mongo is irrelevant. I've tried it both ways, to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: My knowledge on Mongo comes from Mongo University which creators of Mongo give online lectures for free. Thats where the source of this information comes from. Have you tried the piece above ? Did it work or what error did it give ?

Comment: @ODelibalta Yep, the proposed solution returns null--you don't need quotes around a key to search in a Mongo console, so the query remains unchanged. That was my first test before posting on Stack.

Comment: @Brennan I said its a best practice thing and I also said side note. No where in my post it says thats the issue. What is this passion against quoting ? I dont get why you people stuck on that more than the actual problem. Good luck and peace out...